# Existence of Local Maxima in Connected Components

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

**Question:** For $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is it true
that there is a local maximum of $g(x) = \frac{f(x)^2}{(x^2+1)^{d+1}}$ in each connected component of $f \neq 0$ where $d = \deg(f)$?

**Comments:** I haven't (yet) found a counter-example for some $f$ and am looking for some ideas for proving whether this is true. It does not appear this can simply be proved by doing calculus and considering $g'(x) = 0 \wedge g(x) \neq 0 \implies g''(x) < 0$.

Comment: Yes, $g$ is bounded on the whole real line and eventually decreasing as $x\to\pm \infty$, hence $g$ has a local minimum on the components with large $\|x\|$. Now note that any local maximum point of of $g$ must lie in the interior of $\{x:f\neq\0\}$ since $g\ge 0$ everywhere. Conversely, every connected component of $\{x:f\neq\0\}$ has a local maximum, since $f$ cannot be identically 0 on the entire component.

Comment: This might be better suited for math.stackexchange.com by the way..

Comment: I agree with some of what you said, however there are choices of $f$ where each connected component of $f \neq 0$ contain one and only one critical point of $g$ (all of which are local maxima). For example, $f = 4-10x^2$. The following figure has three connected components where $f$ and $g$ are the red and blue curves, respectively: http://i.imgur.com/xRhLV.png

Comment: How does that contradict what I wrote?